# I want to be able to use scanf to type in a person's name and then have a sentence about that person come up individually

Tags: c

When i type in the code bellow, the program complies and runs but when i type in a person's name all of the printf functions for all names show up as the output.  Any suggestions?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{ 

char *Name = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
char *Carson = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
char *David = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
char *Avery = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
char *Taylor = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
char *Brian = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);


printf("Enter a name:\n");
scanf("%s\n",Name);

printf("%s Hello Carson\n", Carson);
printf("%s What are you looking at me for, I dont have any gum!!\n", David);
printf("%s Good luck with volleyball this weekend!!\n", Avery);
printf("%s Unauthorized user. Please back away!\n", Taylor);
printf("%s Hello user.\n", Brian);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: `malloc` returns a pointer. All the variables are of type `char`, but they should be `char *`.

Comment: Please read some good basic C books/tutorials.

Comment: I've tried that and it does the same thing

Comment: This is because your program invokes undefined behavior. None of the variable except name has been initialized.

Comment: A side note: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, therefore you don't need those multiplications.

Comment: You want to invoke different behavior, depending on the input. The fundamental structure of expressing conditional execution in C and most similar languages is the `if` (of which you don't have any in your code, yet). Look it up, understand how to write it and what to expect from it, then try it with something simpler than a string, like an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when you do

```
scanf("%s\n",Name);
```

you put the string from the standard input in "Name".

And when you do :

```
printf("%s Hello Carson\n", Carson);
```

you print the string "Carson" but there is nothing in it.

Try to do :

```
printf("%s Hello Carson\n", Name);
```

because you have already put value in "Name".

***You can also read some book, this is very early learning c language.***